# dropdownlist not changing charttype

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, charts

i have a problem with my code below, i need to make a page that displays a chart, and a drop down list to change the chart type

the chart displays correctly but the dropdownlist control does nothing, can anyone help? i also want the option to go 3D on the 3 chart types

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="admin_test" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function showContent(i) {
      if (document.getElementById('statContent' + i).style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById('statContent' + i).style.display = 'block';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('statContent' + i).style.display = 'none';
      }
  } 
</script> 
            choose chart display type: 
<asp:dropdownlist id="ChartTypeList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
CssClass="spaceright" Width="112px">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Column" Selected="True">Column 2D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Column">Column 3D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Line">Line 2D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Line">Line 3D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pie">Pie 2D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pie">Pie 3D</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:dropdownlist><br />

 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
  <series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" XValueMember="suburb" 
      YValueMembers="username">
    </asp:Series>
  </series>
  <chartareas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
    </asp:ChartArea>
  </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT suburb, COUNT(username) AS username FROM member GROUP BY suburb">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any function listed for `OnSelectedIndexChanged` for you dropdownlist. you are telling it to postback but not telling it what it should.

you should have something like:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ChartTypeList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
CssClass="spaceright" Width="112px" onselectedindexchanged="ChartTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

and for the codebehind

```
protected void ChartTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//change the chart code
}
```

Comment: the changes you suggest do not work (onselectedindexchanged="ChartTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged") and (protected void ChartTypeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e))

Comment: in what sense "does not work"? Are you getting errors? post the code that created as an edit to your question so we have some sense of what you tried doing.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it myself, just thought i'd post it for the good of anyone searching
here is the correct code behind:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged
    'keep charts hidden when not selected
    If (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "hide") Then
        Chart1.Visible = False
        'Columns
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Column 3D") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
        Chart1.Visible = True
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Column") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False
        Chart1.Visible = True

        'Pies
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Pie 3D") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
        Chart1.Visible = True
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Pie") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False
        Chart1.Visible = True

        'Lines
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Line 3D") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
        Chart1.Visible = True
    ElseIf (DropDownList.SelectedValue = "Line") Then
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        Chart1.ChartAreas(0).Area3DStyle.Enable3D = False
        Chart1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

here is the correct code:

```
 <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                    <asp:ListItem value="hide" Selected="True">Select</asp:ListItem> 
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pie">Pie Chart</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Pie 3D">Pie Chart 3D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Column" >Column Chart</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Column 3D">Column Chart 3D</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Line">Line Chart</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Line 3D">Line Chart 3D</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:dropdownlist><br />

 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="450px" Height="450px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Visible="false"  >
      <series>
         <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="suburb" YValueMembers="username">
         </asp:Series>
      </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
 </asp:Chart>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT suburb, COUNT(username) AS username FROM member GROUP BY suburb">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```